# Paragraph bounding boxes using pytesseract

Tags: python, tesseract, image-segmentation, python-tesseract

I have a receipt image and I am trying to use Pytesseract in order to draw bounding boxes around paragraphs of text of the receipt . The problem is that Tesseract is identifying the regions for bounding boxes as per letter not per block.

I am also aware of the different page segmentation modes of Tesseract , though I have tried them all and nothing worked. Is there something that I am missing ?

This is what I have tried so far :

```
import cv2
import pytesseract
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

filename = 'optimized_scanned_images/test1.jpg'
img = cv2.imread(filename)
h, w, _ = img.shape
boxes = pytesseract.image_to_boxes(img, config='-psm 5 load_system_dawg = False load_freq_dawg=False')

for b in boxes.splitlines():
    b = b.split(' ')
    img = cv2.rectangle(img, (int(b[1]), h - int(b[2])), (int(b[3]), h - int(b[4])), (0, 255, 0), 1)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10, 6))
ax.imshow(img)
ax.set_axis_off()
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Comment: you need to use x2 `-` in order to set psm mode. See [tesseract CLI usage](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage#tesseract---help-extra)

Comment: @DmitriiZ. I tried that with no success

Comment: Also `load_system_dawg = False load_freq_dawg=False` has no effect for the CLI. You need to either pass it with `-c` option and without space or use config file. Please read CLI usage page.